# error CS1061: 'Dictionary<string, Content>' does not contain a definition for 'EnsureCapacity'

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I'm programming in C# in Unity. I need to create content system where every content element(model, texture etc.) has unique id and we have content repository that has dictionary of every content element whose key is the content id. This is how it looks
`private Dictionary<string, Content> _itemsMap = new Dictionary<string, Content>();` For not to allocate too much memory I tried to use EnsureCapacity function -`_itemsMap.EnsureCapacity(_originals.Capacity);` where `_originals` - list of all content elements, but I dont found it in list of avaliable fuctions.  Also if if I still use this function, the unity will give an error: **error CS1061: 'Dictionary<string, Content>' does not contain a definition for 'EnsureCapacity' and no accessible extension method 'EnsureCapacity' accepting a first argument of type 'Dictionary<string, Content>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).** So I dont know where the problem is cause I use `System.Collections.Generic`. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Btw earlier uinty version was  *2019.4.22* but I upgraded it to *2020.3.32* so maybe that's why it doesn't work

Comment: There isn’t that in Dictionary

Comment: Some of the generic types in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace have an `EnsureCapacity()` method.  `Dictionary<,>` does not.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, Please edit your question a bit, you wrote everything together like a story.

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews But what about this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.ensurecapacity?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: @Ilya Ah, you're right.  I saw that some of the other `Generic` types got an `EnsureCapacity()` method in .NET 6 or 7, but didn't see that not only did `Dictionary<,>` get one, too, it's had it since .NET Core/Standard 2.1.  I've not worked with Unity but my understanding is it uses Mono and not Microsoft's .NET, so Microsoft's documentation might not be the place to be looking for what types and members are available to you.  I do [see](https://unity.com/releases/2021-lts/programming) a newer release adds support for .NET Standard 2.1, so if you can upgrade to that maybe it will work.